# Can you use pattern matching to bind the last element of a list?

Tags: haskell

Since there is a way to bind the head and tail of a list via pattern matching, I'm wondering if you can use pattern matching to bind the last element of a list?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, you can, using the `ViewPatterns` extension.

```
Prelude> :set -XViewPatterns
Prelude> let f (last -> x) = x*2
Prelude> f [1, 2, 3]
6
```

Note that this pattern will always succeed, though, so you'll probably want to add a pattern for the case where the list is empty, else `last` will throw an exception.

```
Prelude> f []
*** Exception: Prelude.last: empty list
```

Also note that this is just syntactic sugar. Unlike normal pattern matching, this is *O(n)*, since you're still accessing the last element of a singly-linked list. If you need more efficient access, consider using a different data structure such as [`Data.Sequence`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers/Data-Sequence.html), which offers *O(1)* access to both ends.

Comment: last throws an exception on an empty list. I'm looking to get away from last,head, fst,snd. Functions that don't handle empty lists well.  Pattern-matching, let (x:xs) = "abcdefg" for example, is what I was referring to in my question. Was hoping there was a similar approach to get the last element, without using unsafe prelude functions.

Comment: @MichaelLitchard: Well, you can for example define a `safeLast` function which returns a `Maybe`, which you can then pattern match on, or perhaps just reverse the list and then use normal pattern matching.

Comment: since it always succeeds it's not much of a "pattern match" at all. `f = (*2) . last` is better.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `ViewPatterns` to do pattern matching at the end of a list, so let's do

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}
```

and use `reverse` as the viewFunction, because it always succeeds, so for example

```
printLast :: Show a => IO ()
printLast (reverse -> (x:_)) = print x
printLast _ = putStrLn "Sorry, there wasn't a last element to print."
```

This is safe in the sense that it doesn't throw any exceptions as long as you covered all the possibilities. 
(You could rewrite it to return a `Maybe`, for example.)

The syntax

`mainFunction (viewFunction -> pattern) = resultExpression`

is syntactic sugar for

`mainFunction x = case viewFunction x of pattern -> resultExpression`

so you can see it actually just reverses the list then pattern matches that, but it feels nicer.
`viewFunction` is just any function you like.
(One of the aims of the extension was to allow people to cleanly and easily use accessor functions 
for pattern matching so they didn't have to use the underlying structure of their data type when 
defining functions on it.)

Answer (score 5):

The other answers explain the `ViewPatterns`-based solutions. If you want to make it more pattern matching-like, you can package that into a `PatternSynonym`:

```
tailLast :: [a] -> Maybe ([a], a)
tailLast xs@(_:_) = Just (init xs, last xs)
tailLast _ = Nothing

pattern Split x1 xs xn = x1 : (tailLast -> Just (xs, xn))
```

and then write your function as e.g.

```
foo :: [a] -> (a, [a], a)
foo (Split head mid last) = (head, mid, last)
foo _ = error "foo: empty list"
```

Answer (score 3):

This is my first day of Haskell programming and I also encountered the same issue, but I could not resolve to use some kind of external artifact as suggested in previous solutions.

My feeling about Haskell is that if the core language has no solution for your problem, then the solution is to transform your problem until it works for the language.

In this case transforming the problem means transforming a tail problem into a head problem, which seems the only supported operation in pattern matching. It turns that you can easily do that using a list inversion, then work on the reversed list using head elements as you would use tail elements in the original list, and finally, if necessary, revert the result back to initial order (eg. if it was a list).

For example, given a list of integers (eg. [1,2,3,4,5,6]), assume we want to  build this list in which every second element of the original list starting from the end is replaced by its double (exercise taken from [Homework1](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/hw/01-intro.pdf) of [this excellent introduction to Haskell](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/lectures.html)) : [2,2,6,4,10,6].

Then we can use the following:

```
revert :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
revert []     = []
revert (x:[]) = [x]
revert (x:xs) = (revert xs) ++ [x]

doubleSecond :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
doubleSecond []       = []
doubleSecond (x:[])   = [x]
doubleSecond (x:y:xs) = (x:2*y : (doubleSecond xs))

doubleBeforeLast :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
doubleBeforeLast l = ( revert (doubleSecond (revert l)) )

main = putStrLn (show (doubleBeforeLast [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]))
```

It's obviously much longer than previous solutions, but it feels more *Haskell-ish* to me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, and congratulations for such a good start! Reversing the list to access the far end is indeed a very Haskellish solution (though it is rather inefficient, but using `last` can be even worse if you need to do it multiple times... if performance is critical and you need to access a last element, then lists aren't a suitable type).

Comment: Thanks. At my rookie level, I am indeed more interested in discovering the Haskell programming idioms, than mesuring their performance impact. I agree it is definitely a worse case to try to use a simply-linked list in reverse order and I guess this is actually the reason why Haskell does not offer tail pattern matching at first. (Haskell lists are implemented using simply-linked lists, right?)

Comment: Correct. Haskell lists are great as stacks, or as infinite streams, but they're really bad for random access, and accessing the far end is no better than accessing any element in the middle.