# Using patterns to find the nth element

Tags: haskell

I'm working through *Learn You A Haskell* in order to come up to speed with the basics of Haskell. I'm very comfortable with both functional programming and pattern matching, but the latter more so with how *Mathematica* does it.

In the same spirit as the naïve implementation of `head` in Chapter 4.1, I proceeded with a naïve implementation of `last` as:

```
last1 :: [a] -> a
last1 (_:x:[]) = x
```

However, calling `last1 [1,2,3,4]` gave an error `Exception: ... Non-exhaustive patterns in function last1`. I understand that this error implies that the pattern specified does not cover all possible inputs and usually, a catch-all pattern is necessary (which I've not provided). However, I'm not exactly sure why I get *this* error for my input.

**Question 1:** My understanding (of my incorrect approach) is that the first element is captured by `_` and the rest get assigned to `x`, which isn't exactly what I had intended. However, shouldn't this give a type error, because I specified `[a] -> a`, but `x` is now a list?

Note that this is *not* about how to write a working `last` function — I know I can write it as (among other possibilities)

```
last2 :: [a] -> a
last2 [x] = x
last2 (_:x) = last2 x
```

**Question 2:** Along the same theme of better understanding pattern matching in Haskell, how can I use pattern matching to pick out the last element or more generally, the `n`th element from a given list, say, `[1..10]`?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7576910/616736) suggests that you can bind the last element using pattern matching with the `ViewPatterns` extension, but it seems strange that there isn't an analogous "simple" pattern like for `head`

In *Mathematica*, I would probably write it as:

```
Range[10] /. {Repeated[_, {5}], x_, ___} :> x
(* 6 *)
```

to pick out the 6th element and

```
Range[10] /. {___, x_} :> x
(* 10 *)
```

to pick out the last element of a non-empty list.

I apologize if this is covered later in the text, but I'm trying to relate each topic and concept as I come across them, to how it is handled in other languages that I know so that I can appreciate the differences and similarities.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To make sense of the result of your first attempt, you need to see how the
list data is defined. Lists enjoy a somewhat special syntax, but you would
write it something like this.

```
data List a = (:) a (List a)
            | []
```

So, your list [1 .. 10] is actually structured as

```
(1 : (2 : (3 : (4 : []))))
```

In addition, due to the right associativity of the (:) operator, your pattern
for last1 actually looks like

```
last1 :: [a] -> a
last1 (_:(x:[])) = x
```

That is why 'x' has same type as an element of your list; it is the first
argument to the (:) constructor.

Pattern matching allows you to deconstruct data structures like lists, but you
need to know what "shape" they have to do so. That is why you cannot directly
specify a pattern that will extract the last element of a list, because there
are an infinite number of lengths a list can have. That is why the working
solution (last2) uses recursion to solve the problem. You know what pattern
a list of length one has and where to find the final element; for everything
else, you can just throw away the first element and extract the last element
of the resulting, shorter, list.

If you wanted, you could add more patterns, but it would not prove that
helpful. You could write it as

```
last2 :: [a] -> a
last2 (x:[])     = x
last2 (_:x:[])   = x
last2 (_:_:x:[]) = x
        ...
last2 (x:xs) = last2 xs
```

But without an infinite number of cases, you could never complete the function
for all lengths of input lists. Its even more dubious when you consider the fact that
lists can actually be infinitely long; what pattern would you use to match that?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! This makes it very clear why it wasn't working. Is there any pattern to match multiple elements? For example, in the `{___, x_}` line in my Mathematica example (at the very end), `___` implies "zero or more" and `_` implies "exactly one". That allows me to discard everything except the last element, since I've now explicitly described the structure of the list. I do understand that it probably is syntactic sugar and the actual recursion/backtracking is hidden under the hood.

Comment: @yoda There is no way to do this (that I know of at least) with Haskell's pattern matching. That seems like a Mathematica specific feature. In general, the design of Haskell usually avoids "special" data types that get lots of extra bells and whistles (except for some of the nice syntax for lists and tuples). Haskell prefers functions over adding extra baggage to the language.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. I can kind of appreciate this philosophy too... forces me to think a bit more. At least, I don't have to worry about learning functional programming alongside it! :)

Comment: What has been left implicit here is that _Haskell only allows pattern matching on constructors_.  The semantics of pattern matching is actually quite "simple" -- see [the Haskell 2010 report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-580003.17).  Haskell 98 had a feature called _n+k patterns_, which is basically what you want but applied to numbers, not lists, but it's since been removed.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to have pattern match get the "last" element without using view patterns.  That is because there is no way to get the last element of a list without using recursion (at least implicitly), and what is more, there is no *decidable* way to get the last element.

Your code

```
last1 (_:x:[]) = x
```

should be parsed like

```
last1 (_:(x:[])) = x
```

which can be de-sugared into

```
last1 a = case a of
               (_:b) -> case b of
                             (x:c) -> case c of
                                           [] -> x
```

having completed this exercise we see what your code does: you have written a pattern that will match a list IF the outermost constructor of a list is a cons cell AND the next constructor is a cons AND the third constructor is a nil.

so in the case of

```
last1 [1,2,3,4]
```

we have

```
last1 [1,2,3,4] 
= last1 (1:(2:(3:(4:[]))))
= case (1:(2:(3:(4:[])))) of
       (_:b) -> case b of
                     (x:c) -> case c of
                                   [] -> x
= case (2:(3:(4:[]))) of
       (x:c) -> case c of
                     [] -> x
= let x = 2 in case (3:(4:[])) of
                    [] -> x
= pattern match failure
```

Comment: This makes it very clear, thank you! I guess I was looking for a pattern like Mathematica's `{___, x_}`, where `___` means "zero or more" and `_` means exactly one, but you're right, this is merely syntactic sugar that hides some kind of recursion/backtracking under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

Your example

```
last1 (_:x:[]) = x
```

only matches lists containing two elements i.e. lists of the form `a:b:[]`. `_` matches the head of the list without binding, `x` matches the following element, and the empty list matches itself.

When pattern matching lists, only the right-most item represents a list - the tail of the matched list.

You can get the nth element from a list with a function like:

```
getNth :: [a] -> Int -> a
getNth [] _ = error "Out of range"
getNth (h:t) 0 = h
getNth (h:t) n = getNth t (n-1)
```

This built-in using the `!!` operator e.g. `[1..10] !! 5`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Yes, I'm aware of the `!!` operator, but I was interested (out of curiosity) in obtaining it solely by pattern matching, something along the lines of my Mathematica example. Your example is helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

You can indeed use `ViewPatterns` to do pattern matching at the end of a list, so let's do:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}
```

and redefine your `last1` and `last2` by reversing the list before we pattern match. 
This makes it *O(n)*, but that's unavoidable with a list.

```
last1 (reverse -> (x:_)) = x
```

The syntax

`mainFunction (viewFunction -> pattern) = resultExpression`

is syntactic sugar for

`mainFunction x = case viewFunction x of pattern -> resultExpression`

so you can see it actually just reverses the list then pattern matches that, but it feels nicer.
`viewFunction` is just any function you like.
(One of the aims of the extension was to allow people to cleanly and easily use accessor functions 
for pattern matching so they didn't have to use the underlying structure of their data type when 
defining functions on it.)

This `last1` gives an error if the list is empty, just like the original `last` does.

`*Main> last []`
`*** Exception: Prelude.last: empty list`
`*Main> last1 []`
`*** Exception: Patterns.so.lhs:7:6-33: Non-exhaustive patterns in function last1`

Well, OK, not exactly, but we can change that by adding

```
last1 _ = error "last1: empty list"
```

which gives you

`*Main> last1 []`
`*** Exception: last1: empty list`

We can of course use the same trick for `last2`:

```
last2 (reverse -> (_:x:_)) = x
last2 _ = error "last2: list must have at least two elements"
```

But it would be nicer to define

```
maybeLast2 (reverse -> (_:x:_)) = Just x
maybeLast2 _ = Nothing
```

You can carry on this way with for example `last4`:

```
last4 (reverse -> (_:_:_:x:_)) = x
```

And you can see that using the `reverse` viewpattern, 
we've changed the semantics of `(_:_:_:x:_)` from
`(ignore1st,ignore2nd,ignore3rd,get4th,ignoreTheRestOfTheList)` to
`(ignoreLast,ignore2ndLast,ignore3rdLast,get4thLast,ignoreTheRestOfTheList)`.

You note that in Mathematica, the number of underscores is used to indicate the number of elements being ignored.
In Haskell, we just use the one `_`, but it can be used for *any* ignored value, and in the presence of the 
asymmetric list constructor `:`, the semantics depend on which side you're on, so in `a:b`, the `a` must mean an 
element and the `b` must be a list (which could itself be `c:d` because `:` is right associative - `a:b:c` means 
`a:(b:c)`). This is why a final underscore in any list pattern reresents `ignoreTheRestOfTheList`, and in the 
presence of the `reverse` viewfunction, that means ignoring the front elements of the list.

The recursion/backtracking that's hidden under the hood in Mathematica is explicit here with the viewFunction `reverse` (which is a recursive function).

Comment: Thanks, your explanation was helpful! :)