# Couldn't match expected type `a' with actual type `[a]'

Tags: haskell

I was able to execute the following code flawlessly

```
myLast :: [a] -> a
myLast [] = error "Can't call myLast on an empty list!"
myLast (x:_) = x
```

but I'm getting this error `` Couldn't match expected type `a' with actual type `[a]'. `a' is a rigid type variable bound by the type signature for myLast :: [a] -> a `` for the following code:

```
myLast :: [a] -> a
myLast [] = error "Can't call myLast on an empty list!"
myLast (_:x) = x
```

I'm a beginner in Haskell and the error message is too greek and latin for me. From what I can understand, the compiler is not able infer the type in the second case. Can someone point me to what is actually happening here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're declaring the input to be a list of type `[a]`, and the rest to be of type `a`.

A list of type `[a]` in Haskell consists of a head of type `a` and a tail, a list of type `[a]`. The cons constructor `:` takes the head and tail as its arguments.

When you deconstruct a list as `(x:y)`, `x` is the head and `y` is the tail. So in your second code fragment, you're binding the *tail* of the list, which has the list type `[a]`, when your type signature requires that you return a value of type `a` (the head being one example).

Answer (score 6):

Having an understanding of what `:` really is will help decrypt the error message. `:` can be thought of as a function which takes an element and a list, and returns a list that whose first element is the first argument and the rest of it is the second argument, or:

```
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

Getting to your function, you wrote `myLast :: [a] -> a`; however, the type of `myLast (_:x) = x` is `myLast :: [a] -> [a]` since the second argument of `:` (which you named `x`) is itself a list.

Additionally, in general when you don't understand something in Haskell, you should take a look at it's type first using `:t` in GHCI.

Answer (score 2):

`(_:x)` matches _ with the head and x with the tail of the list.  The type of tail of a list is [a].  You are trying to return [a]' where as the function declaration specifies return type as a.

```
myLast (_:x) = x
```

If you want to match last element take a look at this answer - [Can you use pattern matching to bind the last element of a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576843/can-you-use-pattern-matching-to-bind-the-last-element-of-a-list)