# Couldn't match expected type ‘[a]’ with actual type ‘a’

Tags: haskell

why is this giving me error?

```
insertAt :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
insertAt n x xs = x1 ++ x ++ x2
    where (x1,x2) = splitAt n xs
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Couldn't match expected type \`a' with actual type \`\[a\]'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16888668/couldnt-match-expected-type-a-with-actual-type-a)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are mixing lists and list elements - you have to pack the element in a singleton list

```
insertAt :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
insertAt n x xs = x1 ++ [x] ++ x2
    where (x1,x2) = splitAt n xs
```

Comment: @ElBazzi just for future reference - please include the actual error you get it is quite helpful for a) yourself b) the ones answering your question

Comment: Also `insertAt n x xs = x1 ++ x : x2` works just fine.