# Pattern Match on First and Last Items of List

Tags: haskell

Is it possible to pattern match on "starts with `f`", then any text, and "ends with `b`?

I tried:

```
f :: String -> Bool
f ('f':xs:'b') = True
f _            = False
```

But I got an error:

```
explore/PatternMatching.hs:2:11:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char]’ with actual type ‘Char’
    In the pattern: 'b'
    In the pattern: xs : 'b'
    In the pattern: 'f' : xs : 'b'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you use pattern matching to bind the last element of a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576843/can-you-use-pattern-matching-to-bind-the-last-element-of-a-list)

Answer (score 7):

There is no easy way to do this without pattern matching language extensions. I would write it as:

```
f :: String -> Bool
f str = case (take 1 str, drop (length str - 1) str) of
    ("f", "b") -> True
    otherwise -> False
```

(Using `take` and `drop` to avoid specially handling case of an empty string that might cause an error when using e.g. `head` or `!!`)

```
Prelude> f "flub"
True
Prelude> f "foo"
False
Prelude> f "fb"
True
Prelude> f "fbbbb"
True
Prelude> f "fbbbbf"
False
Prelude> f ""
False
```

Comment: What do you mean by `pattern matching language extensions`? Is that provided in your answer, or it's something else? thanks

Comment: My answer doesn't use any extensions, just a plain `case` statement. By "extension" I mean specifically the [ViewPatterns](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ViewPatterns) language extension, [as described in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576843/can-you-use-pattern-matching-to-bind-the-last-element-of-a-list). This is a flag you provide to the compiler / interpreter to let it know about a non-standard language feature that will be enabled (in this case, fancier pattern matching in equational definitions).

Comment: Why use pattern matching instead of just `==` here?

Comment: @dfeuer You're quite right. If the actual, real-life desired functionality was literally to just match to "f" and "b" in this post, it would be a one-liner with `==`. I assumed that this was a toy problem meant to ask about this kind of pattern matching because the actual operations to do would be more involved (as in, it will do different function calls in the case statements), so I opted to write it in a way that resembled the pattern match. But your point is a good one.

Answer (score 2):

As the previous answers state, there's no way to pattern-match directly for this. One might implement it as follows:

```
f 'f':xs@(_:_) = last xs == 'b'  -- @(_:_) ensures nonempty tail
f _            = False
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible directly.

`:` wants a list element on the left side, and a list on the right side.

`'f':xs:'b'` is invalid because there's something that is not a list on the right side of the second `:`.

`'f':xs:"b"` would be valid but won't do what you want, because `xs` is inferred to be a list element, not a list.

I would do this:

```
f s = f' (s, reverse s) where
   f' ('f':_, 'b':_) = True
   f' _              = False
```

Testing:

```
*Main> f ""
False
*Main> f "f"
False
*Main> f "b"
False
*Main> f "fb"
True
*Main> f "feeeeeeeb"
True
*Main> f (repeat 'b')
False
*Main> f (repeat 'f')
(hangs indefinitely)
```

Answer (score 1):

For a list-like data-structure allowing you to access both its first and last element *in constant time*, you may want to have a look at Hinze and Paterson's fingertrees.

They are shipped by e.g. [containers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-Sequence.html) and [here are the relevant views](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-Sequence.html#g:6) to deconstruct them. You may want to write your own view combining deconstruction on the left and the right if you are using this pattern a lot:

```
data ViewLR a = EmptyLR | SingleLR a | BothSides a (Seq a) a

viewlr :: Seq a -> ViewLR a
viewlr seq =
  case viewl seq of
    EmptyL     -> EmptyLR
    hd :< rest ->
      case viewr rest of
        EmptyR       -> SingleLR hd
        middle :> tl -> BothSides hd middle tl
```

You may also want to read up on [View Patterns](https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/posts/2014-12-02-view-patterns.html) to be able to "pattern match" on the left rather than having to use `case ... of`.

Answer (score 0):

Define a dedicated `String` data type and hence a form of pattern matching, for instance consider

```
data HString = Ends Char Char | Plain String 
  deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Thus

```
f :: HString -> Bool
f (Ends h l) = (h,l) == ('f','b')
f (Plain "") = False
f (Plain xs) = f $ Ends (head xs) (last xs)
```

and so

```
*Main> f (Plain "")
False
*Main> f (Plain "fabs")
False
*Main> f (Plain "fab")
True
```

**Update**

Similarly, consider the use of an infix operator `:-:` to denote a constructor, e.g

```
infixr 5 :-:

data HString = Char :-: Char | Plain String 
  deriving (Show, Eq)
```

and thus

```
f :: HString -> Bool
f (h :-: l)  = (h,l) == ('f','b')
f (Plain "") = False
f (Plain xs) = f $ (head xs) :-: (last xs)
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand the error simply check the signature of : operator

```
Prelude> :t (:)
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

It can accept an element and a list to give the appended list. When you supply 'f':xs:'b', then it doesn't match the function call.