# How to pattern match the end of a list?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, pattern-synonyms

Say I wanted to remove all zeros at the end of a list:

```
removeEndingZeros :: (Num a, Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
removeEndingZeros (xs ++ [0]) = removeEndingZeros xs
removeEndingZeros xs          = xs
```

This does not work because of the `(++)` operator in the argument. How can I determine the end of a list through pattern-matching?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you use pattern matching to bind the last element of a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576843/can-you-use-pattern-matching-to-bind-the-last-element-of-a-list)

Comment: What about reversing the problem can you remove leading zeroes? And if you are not restricted to using lists then Data.Sequence might be of use

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a function in `Data.List` to do this:

```
dropWhileEnd :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
dropWhileEnd p = foldr (\x xs -> if p x && null xs then [] else x : xs) []
```

So you can drop the trailing zeros with

```
dropWhileEnd (== 0)
```

---

Another, very similar, function can be implemented like this:

```
dropWhileEnd2 :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
dropWhileEnd2 p = foldr (\x xs -> if null xs && p x then [] else x : xs) []
```

`dropWhileEnd2 p` has exactly the same semantics as `reverse . dropWhile p . reverse`, but can reasonably be expected to be faster by a constant factor. `dropWhileEnd` has different, non-comparable strictness properties than the others (it's stricter in some ways and less strict in others).

Can you figure out circumstances under which each can be expected to be faster?